# SDK 22.2.0 faild to sync

Tags: android, gradle, sdk, android-appcompat

I just updated my build.gradle app file with the new SDK 22.2.0

until now I can't sync the file because android studio ask me to install the sdk when I press install he give me this error:

[image]

this is my build.gradle app file source code :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.2.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.kimo.kimo.pillreminder"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
}
```

help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the error

in order to

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
```

you need to change

```
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
```

I don't now why??

but it solve the sync issue.

Comment: The last version is 22.0.1, there isn't Build-tools 22.2.0